# Wants to get Time array

Tags: ios, swift, time

I am trying to get time array where time will start from current time + 1 hour and after that till 5 pm it will show 30-30 min Difference between time.

```
func getTimeArray(){
    let date = Date()
    var dateComponents = DateComponents()
    let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()

    let calendar = Calendar.current
    var components = calendar.dateComponents([.hour , .minute], from: date)

    dateComponents.hour = components.hour
    dateComponents.minute = components.minute
    timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    guard let startTime = calendar.date(from: dateComponents) else {
        return }
    for i in 0 ... 10 {
        guard let  newDate = calendar.date(byAdding: .minute , value: i + 30, to: startTime) else {return}
        timeArray.append(timeFormatter.string(from: newDate).localizedUppercase)
        print(timeArray)
    }

    print(timeArray)

}
```

and Result is :- ["12:53 PM", "12:54 PM", "12:55 PM", "12:56 PM", "12:57 PM", "12:58 PM", "12:59 PM", "1:00 PM", "1:01 PM", "1:02 PM", "1:03 PM"]
I need :- ["12:30", "1:00", "1:30", "2:00"]

Answer (score 1):

A more structured way for your need:

```
func getTimeArray(){
        var timeArray = [String]()
        let timeFormatter = DateFormatter()
        timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm"

        for i in 0 ... 10 {
            guard let dt:Date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30*i, to: Date()) else {return}
            timeArray.append(timeFormatter.string(from: dt).localizedUppercase)

        }
        print(timeArray)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its all about how you set **date format**. You can refer for different time formats [NSDateFormatter.com](http://nsdateformatter.com/)

**Your Fix:**

Change `timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"` to `timeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm"`